# How to move cursor on EditText line one space to the right of the user input data on the line?

Tags: android-edittext, cursor

I have a fragment that sets a user input date on an EditText line.  I'd like to have the cursor move to the end of the date and then one additional space to the right.

The below code moves the cursor to the end of the date, but how do I move the cursor the one additional space to the right of the date?

```
...
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Comment: You need to add/append a space to the text

Comment: That did the trick.  I added a space using " " to the String and then the setSelection method above moves the cursor to the end of the length of the Sting (the text plus the additional one space.